# C commands executing all at once in eclipse

Tags: c

I am trying to run a simple C program in eclipse where the program will output a question to the user, prompting the user to input a number.  The program should then output that number back to the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
        /*Can machines ever live?*/
        printf("Hello There. \n"  );
/* why is this not printing
 *  */
        int num;
        printf("enter a number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &num );
        printf("you have entered %d", num);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

The problem is when I am running the program, no output is given to me upon the running of the program.  If I run the code, then all the output is given to me at once (both the prompt and the outputted print with the number.)  The output ends up looking like this:

7
Hello There.
enter a number:
you have entered 7

Comment: Could you try to add something like `fflush(stdout);`  before `scanf()` ?

Comment: fflush(stdout) worked.  I've searched a bit and it seems like this command shouldn't need to be used unless my compiler isn't working properly.  This may have to do with me running gcc in a windows environment.

Comment: Indeed the two standard streams should be line buffered and you should see the result as soon as a newline is sent. It's either the library not behaving correctly, or there's some magic in Eclips which breaks it, you can try to run the program from the windows command line.

Answer (score 0):

The ISO C standard states that `stdout` may be *fully* buffered (as opposed to line buffered) if the output device can be definitively determined to not be interactive (see `C11 7.21.3 Files /3` and `/7` for details).

A fully buffered stream won't care about newlines, it will happily buffer all your data until the buffer (for example, 4K of data) is full or the stream is closed.

This is generally for efficiency since flushing buffers often is relatively expensive. The reason it's done for interactive I/O is that you generally want the user to receive information immediately.

The likelihood is that you are running your code *within* the IDE and it's detecting that as a non-interactive device.

To fix it, you could flush standard output after each `printf` with something like:

```
fflush (stdout);
```

or you could change it to line buffering once somewhere at the start of your program, though support for this is, I believe, implementation dependent):

```
setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, BUFSIZ);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on paxidiablo answer:
I **do not** suppose that `the output device can be definitively determined to not be interactive` if you run Eclipse with a typical compiler. Therefore I **would not assume** that what you see is: `stdout fully buffered`.
I think that a more probable cause is that for some reasons (this may be a bug in Eclipse, or your omission) the executable code that you run is not the result of compiling the source code that you see, but one of its previous versions.
I believe restarting Eclipse and recompiling the program afresh should help here.